# PowerShell - Loop through all SharePoint Website & continue when an error occurred

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"
$webApp = "Https://SharePointSite.com"
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication -identity $webApp
foreach ($site in $wa.Sites) {
   foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
       $siteURL = $web.Url
     Write-Host $siteURL
   }
}
```

The problem is that when it hits the statement ***foreach ($site in $wa.Sites)***, and it cannot get the site due to access denied or any error, it would stop.  I would like to continue. I tried to TRY CATCH FINALLY, and it still stops when it encounters an error.

I tried to put in ***-ErrorAction Continue***, but it gives me an error message as 
you must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator

How do I get around it so it would continue to the site?

I really appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear which step is generating the error. Can you please post the exact error messages? Also, *where* did you try to "put in `-ErrorAction Continue`"? The **Get-SPWebApplication** command? Can you post the version with **try/catch/finally** and the error message for that as well?  BTW, to format a block of code, indent the whole block by 4 spaces (you can select it and click the `{}` symbol) rather than putting backticks around each line (those are for inline code). Use block quotes for the error messages by adding a `>` as the first character.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `try..catch`, then you must throw terminating errors. Non-terminating errors are not handles by a `try..catch` block.

```
try {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction Stop;
    $webApp = "Https://SharePointSite.com"
    $wa = Get-SPWebApplication -identity $webApp -ErrorAction Stop;
    foreach ($site in $wa.Sites) {
       foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
           $siteURL = $web.Url
         Write-Host $siteURL
       }
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host -Object ('Error occurred: {0}' -f $_);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Trevor for the Try/Catch error catch block.  I also have finally.  The error message that I received when it opens the website is Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. +categoryInfo: Not Specified: (:) [], TargetInvocationException. +FullyQuaflifiedErrorID: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException. The reason I received this error because the ID that running the script does not have access to this site.  But I would like the process to continue.  I can fix this problem later.  I added the ErrorAction Continue at:

Comment: foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs -ErrorAction Continue)